# Allocate based on arguments

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a program which takes input from either a file or standard in, depending on whether a command line argument is passed. To do this, I'm using getopts, which allows you to get an `Option<String>` with the value of the argument. If the value is `Some(filename)` I want to open that file and create a buffered reader over it. If it's `None`, I want to set the stream to stdin.

```
let input: Box<Read> = match matches.opt_str("i") {
    Some(ifname) => Box::new(BufReader::new(File::open(ifname).unwrap())),
    None => Box::new(io::stdin()),
};
```

So, the type of input either needs to be `&read` or `Box<Read>`, since `Stdin` and `BufReader` are incompatible types. Obviously `&Read` won't work since there's no variable actually owning the object that stays in scope for long enough. So I tried using `Box<Read>`, but this still gives me an error about `input` not living long enough.

What would be the rust (rusty? rustic?) way of doing something like this?

MCVE:

```
use std::io;
use std::borrow::BorrowMut;
use std::io::{BufReader,BufWriter,Read,Write};
use std::fs::File;

fn rc4(key: &[u8], input: &mut Read, output: &mut Write) {
    // Read and write here                                                                                                                                                                           
}

fn main() {
    let mut input: Box<Read> = match Some("file-from-parser.txt") {
        Some(ifname) => Box::new(BufReader::new(File::open(ifname).unwrap())),
        None => Box::new(io::stdin()),
    };

    rc4(&[1u8, 2, 3], input.borrow_mut(), &mut io::stdout());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code works:

```
use std::io;
use std::io::{BufReader, Read, Write};
use std::fs::File;

fn rc4(key: &[u8], input: &mut Read, output: &mut Write) {
    // Read and write here                                                                                                                                                                           
}

fn main() {
    let mut input: Box<Read> = match Some("file-from-parser.txt") {
        Some(ifname) => Box::new(BufReader::new(File::open(ifname).unwrap())),
        None => Box::new(io::stdin()),
    };

    rc4(&[1u8, 2, 3], &mut input, &mut io::stdout());
}
```

Note that there is absolutely no reason to use `borrow_mut()` because references to `Box` pointers are automatically coerced to references to their internals when necessary. Also, it would be more idiomatic to make `rc4` consume references to generic types instead of trait objects:

```
fn rc4<R: Read, W: Write>(key: &[u8], input: &mut R, output: &mut W)
```

or even

```
fn rc4<R: Read, W: Write>(key: &[u8], input: R, output: W)
```

(this works because `&mut R` is `Read` if `R` is `Read`, and the same thing holds for `Write`; you would probably need to write `mut input: R` and/or `mut output: W` depending on the API you use)

The code above will work without changes with both these signatures.

As for why `borrow_mut()` does not work, I don't have any ideas. It looks to me that it should work. Maybe this is some kind of interaction with the fact that `Box<Read>` is a trait object.

Also, there is a way to avoid `Box` entirely:

```
fn main() {
    let mut i1;
    let mut i2;
    let mut input: &mut Read = match Some("file-from-parser.txt") {
        Some(ifname) => {
            i1 = BufReader::new(File::open(ifname).unwrap());
            &mut i1
        }
        None => {
            i2 = io::stdin();
            &mut i2
        }
    };

    rc4(&[1, 2, 3], input, &mut io::stdout());
}
```

Here we store each reader in separate variables and return a reference to one of them.

Comment: I tried to use this signature: `fn rc4<R: Read, W: Write>(key: &[u8], input: R, output: W)` but had to change it to `fn rc4<R: Read, W: Write>(key: &[u8], input: R, mut output: W)` to get it to compile. The signature of `write` requires a mut borrow of `self`. The reason I didn't need a mut borrow of input is because the `Read.bytes()` iterator does not require self to be mut or even a borrow, for some reason. Not sure how that works.

Comment: Yes, indeed you're right about `mut output`. As for why `bytes()` works, that's because it *consumes* the `Read` instance it is called on. It then can do whatever it wants to, including storing the consumed value inside a mutable slot, making it mutable.